# How to update data in one arraylist with two arrayadapter in different activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use two different ArrayAdapter(separately in to two Activity) with one Arraylist. The first ArrayAdapter does the Increment for the Quantity and the second does the Decrement. Then all of the Data from the first ArrayAdapter will be transfer to the second ArrayAdapter, but only the Data with Quantity greater than 1 will be displayed. All of the previous task seems to be working fine, until I tried to Decrement a Quantity(It shows that the data decements) and try to check if changes were saved by going back to the first Activity and back again to the second Activity. What happens is that changes made by the Decrement is being ignored and resets the data from when the item was Incremented. I know it's kinda messed up, but I hope you can help me what am I doing wrong.

EDIT: I am using two ArrayAdapter because I want to display the quantity in the second adapter, along with other elements.

Here is my codes:

myProductAdapter.java(Increment Adapter)

```
public class myProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myProduct> {

    public class ViewHolder{
        Button addItem;
    }

    public myProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myProduct> myProducts) {
        super(context, 0, myProducts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final myProduct product = getItem(position);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        //Some Codes Here..

        viewHolder.addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                product.productQuantity ++;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + product.productQuantity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

myOrderAdapter.java(Decerement Adapter)

```
public class myOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myProduct> {

    public class ViewHolder{
        Button minusItem;
    }

    public myOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myProduct> orders){
        super(context, 0, orders);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final myProduct order = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.minusItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                order.productQuantity --;
                if(order.productQuantity() <= 0){
                    order.productQuantity = 0;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"" + order.productQuantity(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

myProduct.java

```
public class myProduct implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("productID")
    public int productID;
    @SerializedName("categoryID")
    public int categoryID;
    @SerializedName("productName")
    public String productName;
    @SerializedName("productPrice")
    public int productPrice;

    public int productQuantity = 0;

    public myProduct(int productID, int categoryID, String productName, int productPrice){
        this.productID = productID;
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public int getProductID(){
        return productID;
    }

    public int getCategoryID(){
        return categoryID;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return productName;
    }

    public int getProductPrice(){
        return productPrice;
    }

    public int productQuantity() {
        return productQuantity;
    }


    protected myProduct(Parcel in) {
        productID = in.readInt();
        categoryID = in.readInt();
        productName = in.readString();
        productPrice = in.readInt();
        productQuantity = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(productID);
        dest.writeInt(categoryID);
        dest.writeString(productName);
        dest.writeInt(productPrice);
        dest.writeInt(productQuantity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<myProduct> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<myProduct>() {
        @Override
        public myProduct createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new myProduct(in);
        }

        @Override
        public myProduct[] newArray(int size) {
            return new myProduct[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Menu.class

```
    viewOrder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.viewOrder);
    viewOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Menu.this, Order.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("productList", productList);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Order.class

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

productList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("productList");
filter = new ArrayList<myProduct>();
orderAdapter = new myOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(),filter);

for(myProduct item : productList){

    if(item.productQuantity > 0){
        Log.d(TAG,item.getProductName());
        Log.d(TAG,"" + item.productQuantity());
        filter.add(item);
    }
    else if(item.productQuantity <= 0){
        filter.remove(item);
    }
}
orderListView.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the array to the second adapter as a Parcelable, so it's basically making a deep copy of the array, and has nothing to do with the original array. Therefore changes in second array, don't show in first array. 
A simple (but maybe dirty) solution would be to make the array as a static variable (or part of the application class, or a singleton), and use the actual array in both activities. 
If you can design, that both lists are in two fragments, and part of one activity, then just have the activity hold on to the shared array for both fragments.